# Doing a natural join in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How does a join in sqlachemy work?

```
class Enrollments(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Enrollments'
    StudentID = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('Student.StudentID'))
    FinalGrade = Column(VARCHAR(3))



class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Student'

    StudentID = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    Name = Column(VARCHAR(100))
    EnrolledIn = relationship('Enrollments')


 session.query(Student).join(Enrollments).all() #what isn't giving me what I expect
```

I'm expecting this to give me three columns (StudentID, Name, FinalGrade, EnrolledIn), but it's only giving me the Student objects without the Enrollments that should be attached, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enrollments are attached to each `Student` object, as `student.EnrolledIn`.

But joins are for querying, not fetching; if you want to eagerload them, you want

```
session.query(Student).options(joinedload(Student.EnrolledIn))
```

Relationship loading is documented here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading

By the way you might want to use `snake_case` for attributes of objects; it's a little confusing to read since `DromedaryCase` is usually reserved for class names only  :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a CamelCase fan myself, but the database we're pulling from is in it. But this was just the lead I needed. Thank you!

Comment: ah, i see.  if you want you can use different names in the ORM and in the db: `student_id = Column('StudentID', INTEGER, primary_key=True)`